# Does "Debug Diagnostics Tool" Full Dump cause garbage collection or restart process?

Tags: asp.net, garbage-collection, memory-dump, debug-diagnostic-tool

So I have a series of ASP.net web apps which are each assigned their own AppPool

This results in several instances of w3wp.exe residing in memory.

I've been trying to figure out why a couple of them steadily increase their use of RAM over the course of a day.

I found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2006817/11356) that "Debug Diagnostics Tool" might be of use:

I downloaded installed and attempted to use it to create a full dump of the process.

For some reason it failed.

However afterwards I noticed that the memory used (private bytes) had dropped from nearly 600Mb down to ~90Mb

**Did DDT cause the app to restart (or recycle), or did some form of garbage collection get invoked and cause the App to release a bunch of memory?**